# Selenium Element is Not Visible Exception on Already Triggered Area

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium

I'm trying to automate entries on a this site: https://gleam.io/jtwmn/3d-printer-giveaway

I'm successfully able to click on the "Visit @nexi_tech on Instagram" link, and the blue button of the same that follows. I then close the popup window that appears, and try to fill in the name and email address in the text boxes shown here ->
[Text boxes I'm trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpyJK.png)

At this point I get the error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element is not visible

Here's the code for my second attempt (first attempt commented out):

```js
# Code running on Python 2.7

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

firefox_profile.add_extension('/Users/samer/Downloads/quickjava-2.0.6-fx.xpi')
firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.curVersion", "2.0.6.1")  # Prevents loading the 'thank you for installing screen'
firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Images", 2)  # Turns images off
firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.AnimatedImage", 2)  # Turns animated images off

# firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.CSS", 2)  ## CSS
# firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Cookies", 2)  ## Cookies
firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Flash", 2)  # Flash
firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Java", 2)  # Java
# firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.JavaScript", 2)  ## JavaScript
firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Silverlight", 2)  # Silverlight

# Logging In
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)
driver.get("https://gleam.io/jtwmn/3d-printer-giveaway")
driver.maximize_window()

window_before = driver.window_handles[0]

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.no-underline.enter-link.instagram-border.clearfix.grey-bg.default").click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn.btn-info.btn-large.btn-embossed.ng-binding").click()
time.sleep(3)

window_after = driver.window_handles[1]

# Switch Windows
driver.switch_to_window(window_after)

# Close new tab after a bit
driver.close()
time.sleep(2)

driver.switch_to_window(window_before)
time.sleep(3)

#Fill In details

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contestant[name]"]').send_keys("John")

# Previous Test
# username = driver.find_element_by_id("contestant[name]")
# emailaddress = driver.find_element_by_id("contestant[email]")

# username.send_keys("John")
# emailaddress.send_keys("john@gmail.com")
time.sleep(5)

#Save Details
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-primary.ng-scope").click()
time.sleep(5)

print "Save Complete"
driver.quit()
print "Script Ended"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try

```
len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@id="contestant[name]"]'))
```

you'll see that it returns `4`! So there are 3 not visible and only one visible `input`. You can try to use index to handle appropriate element:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@id="contestant[name]"]')[3].send_keys("John")
```

Comment: Awesome! That works perfectly. Small follow-up question. For the button to Save Details, I get "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException:" after inputing the data. I assume there's also multiple buttons of the same.
Any idea how I can click that specific one?

Comment: Try this one `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[text()="Save"]')[2].click()`. Don't forget to mark this answer as *Accepted* if it solved your issue :)

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated.