# input tags in html code change when using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have been using selenium to try and automate competition entries on [Gleam](https://gleam.io/). I had posted a question earlier about problems with finding tags but I eventually got it working by finding the iframe. However, the class tag that I used to enter my FULL_NAME has disappeared and does not exist anymore. It was the only tag that made the input tag unique.

So my question is, are the HTML tags changing when I reload the page? If so, why? and how can I distinguish between input tags when everything about them (i.e. id, name, class etc.) is exactly the same?

Here is my code if anyone wants to try and automate this site:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/<MY_NAME>/Documents/Automate_Login_py/chromedriver')

browser.get(('https://gleam.io/contest/airpods-pro'))

frame= "GleamEmbedzcR0I"
browser.switch_to.frame

# The below @class tag is not showing anymore
enterName = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class= 'ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched']")

enterName.send_keys('John Smith')
```

**Edit:** added HTML code

```html
<input id="contestant[name]" name="name" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 300 }" ng-model="contestantState.form.name" ng-pattern=".*" placeholder="Alice Smith" required="" style="width: 246px" type="text" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern">
```

Comment: Please add the html of the element you are trying to operate on

Comment: Have added the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the id is present in the HTML structure, you can use that to get your element.

```
enter_name=browser.find_element_by_id("contestant[name]")
enter_name.send_keys("John Smith")
```

Comment: This exact html strip appears 6 or 7 times throughout the code so it is not unique. The class I showed in my question used to be there ( making it unique) now it isn’t there.

Comment: @d789w  All the other strips have tag `name="name"` as well ?

Comment: Yes, everything is exactly the same (I.e. I’d, name, class etc)

Comment: @d789w then you can use the index of the element by fetching in the element in a list and then use the index of that element

Comment: Great, I will give that a go. Thanks for the help